# Git with a "two-stage remote"

Tags: git, github

I have a project hosted on GitHub and I would like to work locally on it. I have multiple Computers that need to access it and I would like to share code between them. However, I do not want all of these commits to go on GitHub, so a simple "clone and then just push/pull" approach does not suit.

Essentially, I want this:

```
[GitHub] --> [A Local Network Share] --> [PC1]
                                     --> [PC2]
```

So PC1 and PC2 should be able to push/pull to the local network share and thus share code between each other, and every once in a while I want to push those changes to my GitHub repository.

I'm a bit lost here - do I just create a branch? Or do I git clone from GitHub to my share and then git clone from my share to PC1 and PC2, which would result them only having 1 remote (the share) and the share only having 1 remote (GitHub)?

*Edit:* It's not for security - I don't mind when all the immediate commits go to GitHub, and I also don't want to prevent PC2 from accessing GitHub. It's more that I don't want to setup the whole SSL stuff and because I am someone who commits very very often (sometimes every few minutes - I use git commit as an extended undo function), and I want the code on GitHub always to be compilable.

**Edit 2:** The solutions here did not work for me yet :( So I do

```
git clone --bare git@github.com:foo/bar
```

on my server. This creates a clone. On my PCs, I git clone this repository - that step works fine, my PCs have a .git repository and my server is set up as a remote.

However, on the server, nothing is set up properly - there are no remotes added and i can't push from there. Adding a remote is easy using git add, but then how do I push? git status says it requires a work dir (which we don't have with --bare), and git push says "Everything up to date" even though it isn't (I made a change on PC1 and git pushed to the Server)

Creating the repository on the server without --bare means that it has it's own work dir, so when I git push from the PCs, the server does not pick that up (I'm guessing I somehow need git pull from the PCs, but I want to avoid that).

Am I missing a step here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second solution should be enough.

- Creating a fork would mean your intermediate stage would still be GitHub ([a fork](http://help.github.com/forking/) is a `git clone` *on* GitHub)
- creating a branch does not solve anything in term of *sharing* code

If you make a `git clone --bare myGitHubRepo.git` on your share, and then clone that sharedRepo on PC1 and PC2, you have set up for each of those PC repo a natural destination for them to push/pull.

**Edit by mstum:** This approach works and is correct, but is missing a step. The bare clone on the server does not have any remotes setup. This needs to be done either with

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:user/Project.git
```

or every push from the Server to gitHub needs to be

```
git push git@github.com:user/Project.git
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite achievable. First make a bare clone of the github repo:

```
git clone --bare git@github:foo \\network\foo
```

The repository is bare(doesn't contain working copy, this is to so that you can clone it locally and push to it).

Then on each PC you clone the network location:

```
git clone \\network\foo foo
```

You then work on each repository and make branches, commits etc and push them to the share. When you are ready to push to github, change into `\\network\foo` and push from there.

Answer (score 0):

Is this for security so that PC2 doesn't have access to push to github? For that, I usually set up multiple http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html'>git remotes from my development machine. Developers that don't have push access to the main remote can push/pull to a separate remote. You can then pull their changes down to a different local branch and merge them in as you see fit.